# Google App Script IF ELSE logic not correct

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google App script that is copying files from one folder to another. First, it checks to see if there are any files in the source folder. If there are, it deletes the files in the target folder and then copies the files from the source folders to the target. Once the copy is complete, it should delete the files from the source folder. However, it is not working as I am expecting it to and I believe the issue is in the `if` `else` statement. I have a `while` loop within the `if` `else` statement. My thoughts was that the `while` loop would finish before it checked the `if` statement, but this does not seem to be the case.

The issue is that the script deletes on of the files in the target folder instead of keeping both of the files. (I only have 2 files right now).

Here is my code:

```
while(sourceFolders.hasNext()){
    var sourceFolder = sourceFolders.next();
    var sourceFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();

    // Check to see if there are new files to copy
    if(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
      //++ If so, delete the files in the target folder  
      deleteTheFiles(TARGET_FOLDER);

      //++ Copy new files to target folder
      while(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
        var sourceFile = sourceFiles.next();
        var sourceFileName = sourceFile.getName();
        sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFileName, TARGET_FOLDER);
        //++ Delete files in source folder
        sourceFile.setTrashed(true);
      }
    //-- If not, do nothing
    } else {
      Logger.log('There are not files at this time.')
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the `deleteTheFiles()` function.  Use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to step through the code line by line.

Comment: Please edit to provide the minimal code that will reproduce the problem.  [mcve]

Comment: I edited it. I hope this helps you help me!

Comment: sourceFiles.hasNext() will only be true if there is more than 1 file. Also, every time your script finds a new folder with files it deletes all the files it just copied to the TargetFolder from the last source folder...

Comment: @Cole9350 Correct. That part seems to work fine. What seems to be happening is the `if` statement is `true` more than once, which leads me to why this is happening. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have more than one folder in the source, the first `while` loop was iterating more than once, thus firing the `deleteTheFiles()` function, which was deleting the first file that was put into the target folder. I made a simple `counter` variable outside of the `while` loop and that solved the issue. Here is the code:

```
function copyFilesToBackup() {  
  var sourceFolders = SOURCE_FOLDER.getFolders();
  var counter = 0; // <-- ADDED THIS COUNTER -->
  while(sourceFolders.hasNext()){ // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    var sourceFolder = sourceFolders.next();
    var sourceFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();

    // Check to see if there are new files to copy
    if(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
      //++ If so, delete the files in the target folder  
      if(counter < 1){ <-- SINCE WE ONLY NEED TO DELETE THE TARGET ONCE -->
        deleteTheFiles(TARGET_FOLDER);
        counter++; <-- INCREMENT COUNTER -->
      }
      //++ Copy new files to target folder
      while(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
        var sourceFile = sourceFiles.next();
        var sourceFileName = sourceFile.getName();
        sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFileName, TARGET_FOLDER);
        //++ Delete files in source folder
        sourceFile.setTrashed(true);
      }
    //-- If not, do nothing
    } else {
      Logger.log('There are not files at this time.')
    }
  }
}
```